# XCode - move files from one folder to another in a SCM aware way?

Tags: svn, xcode

I have an XCode project in SVN.
I would like to relocate some files from one physical directory to another but can't seem to find a way to do this in XCode.
If I do the move in XCode it simply moves the file references from one Group folder to the next, without changing their location on disk.
If I move the files in Organizer - well Organizer seems to be SVN unaware as Ive just spent the afternoon manually unwinding the move so that I can do a check in.
At the moment my only option(s) seem to be:
1. lots of svn command line mojo, or
2. do a checkout on windows where TortiseSVN can be used to do all kinds of stuff (But then my XCode project will be all confused).

I'm really hoping ive missed something...

Comment: Why does it matter to you that only the references to the files are being moved? You're not using inode numbers to find them. I would think that saving a bunch of disk thrashing would be a good thing. Are the directories on different volumes?

Comment: I have created all the groups in my xcode project as the "relative to enclosing folder" type, so that the group structure of my xcodeproj maps to the folder structure that the xcodeproj is saved in.
I would like to maintain the parity between the folder structure and XCode project structure so that browsing either one (i.e. in XCode or Finder) yields the same file layout.

Comment: It's same with Xcode 4.2. You move files using SVN commands and manually change files property to point to moved files. No good..

Comment: Gosh, 7 years later and we still have to move files with a 3rd party tool!!! And what is even more undignified - using TortoiseSVN ON WINDOWS  looks the most decent way for this task. This is just disgrace from Apple...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there appears to be no way to do a svn copy in Xcode 4. Your only options for management of subversion repositories in the Xcode organizer are: Make Directory, Delete, and import.  And as for dealing with committed files and folders, the options are commit, update, Add, and Ignore. So as you suggested you are going to need to do some svn command line work, or find your self a better GUI svn client. I use to use [SvnX](http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/community/subversion/svnx/)  when I worked full time with svn. But yes your best bet if you don't want to work in the command line is to find a good GUI svn client, there are a few to choose from see [Best subversion client for Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899/best-subversion-client-for-mac-os).